# How to find replacement for a discontinued thermistor component?

Tags: sensor, temperature, thermistor, alternatives

I am in need of a thermistor with characteristics, such as those of now discontinued KTY84-130 [(link to datasheet)](http://www.nxp.com/products/sensors/temperature-sensors/silicon-temperature-sensors:KTY84). I am after the exceptional linearity it features and also temperature range, up to ~ 250-300 °C. Its low price was also a plus.

**How do I find out what's a good replacement thermistor I could use instead?**

Comment: From current personal experience and anecdotally from others problems with Ali etc vendors are not uncommon. Counterfeit, used / broken etc.

Comment: Use a reputable distributor or the manufacturer is the first and only port of call in my experience.

Comment: The KTY84 will not RIP for long time yet, try other delaer, producer.

Comment: I like digikey for searching for stuff.  they still have a few kty83's.  http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=%09568-11396-1-ND  You could look for something similar.  Say is that thing a diode?  (The thermistors I know go both ways. :^)

Comment: That's usually the range of RTD's and Thermocouples

Answer (score 0):

Low Cost, High resistance semiconductor thermal sensors at 300'C appear to be going off the market for various reasons.  Reliability being foremost.

Another e.g. http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nxp-semiconductors/KTY84-130,113/568-3254-2-ND/1068979

Thin Film Platinum Resistor technology appears to be the best for automotive low cost, fast response, high-rel for EGR and other applications. Up to 300'C

e.g. http://sensata.com/sensors/automotive-sensor-darts500-e.htm  Custom parts are avail, if you have high volume demand.

If your volume is low with multiple sensors used, thermocouple wire and shared electronics could be an option or remote IR detection of heat radiation.

Answer (score -4):

You can use LM34 (Fahrenheit calibrated) or LM35 (Celcius calibrated)

Comment: No you can't, it only goes to 150C.